# ¿Cómo puedo resolver error jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException (Java,Mysql)?

Tags: java, mysql, angular

Hice una conexión mediante `spring boot` y sin embargo me marca errores al momento de guardar junto con angular al dar `save` me sale este error el problema es que al ejecutar `postman` funciona correctamente la `api` alguien sabe algo acerca de este problema no se por que cuando quiero guardar datos aparece este tipo de errores.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Column 'password' cannot be null  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1040)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)

```
public Connection getConection(){
    Connection con=null;
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/profiledb","root","root");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}

@Override
public int saveprofile(ProfileDto prof) {
    int status=0;
    try{
        Connection con = getConection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into profileuser(name,user,email,number,password) values(?,?,?,?,?)");
        ps.setString(1,prof.getName());
        ps.setString(2, prof.getUser());
        ps.setString(3,prof.getEmail());
        ps.setString(4,prof.getNumber());
        ps.setString(5,prof.getPassword());
        status = ps.executeUpdate();
    }catch (Exception f){
        f.printStackTrace();
    }
    return status;
}
```

Y aquí les dejo el código de angular:

```
this.save = {
  'id': '',
  'name': this.name,
  'user': this.user,
  'email': this.email,
  'number': this.number,
  'password': this.password
};
 this.getprofiles.getsave(this.save).subscribe(data =>{
   console.log(data);
```

y mi html espero que puedan ayudarme

```
 <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 movingpixel">
      <h1 style="color: white">Register Here</h1>
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-labelledby="namehelp" placeholder="" name="name" required [(ngModel)]="name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="user">User:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" aria-labelledby="userhelp" placeholder="" name="user" required [(ngModel)]="user">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email"  name="email" required [(ngModel)]="email">
          <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="number">Numberphone:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number" aria-labelledby="numberhelp" placeholder="" name="number" required [(ngModel)]="number">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password" name="password" [ngModel]="password" required >
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveData()">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 movingpixel3">
        <img class="imgsize" src="../../assets/img/register.png">
      <h3 class="text-center newmargintop">Please Fill All The Fields</h3>
      <p class="text-center" style="color: white">If you have any question please send any email to administrator</p>
    <p class="text-center" style="color: red">Copyright: <a href="" style="color: white">@teamsolution.com</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Estas guardando la password como null cuando la bbdd no lo permite. Depura y ve porque el valor llega como null.

Comment: Hola JDev ya depure el programa pero esta muy raro qu eme lo mande null por que cuando lo mando con postman al momento de recibirlo creo que este problema puede venir de angular pero esta raro seguire depurandolo aver si encuentro el problema

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude resolver el problema Este Div Era el problema :)

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password" name="password" [ngModel]="password" required >
    </div>
```

y esta es la soluicion

```
div class="form-group">
         <label>password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required="" [(ngModel)]="password">
        </div>
```